# Is it possible to use the ternary operator for an if, if else, without a final else?

Tags: javascript, conditional-operator

I've recently become informed of the ternary operator and it seems like an effective way of cleaning up my code. However, I seem to be confused with the possibilities of it.

I understand that you cannot use it for if-only conditions, but I'm a little confused about the logic of what I've done.

I wrote this:

```
if(current_slide < 1){
    current_slide = 1;
    ToggleEnabled(next_button);
}else if(current_slide > total_slides){
    current_slide = 1;
    ToggleEnabled(prev_button);
}
```

It works, whatever. I wanted to clean it up a little, so I made this:

```
    current_side < 1 ? (ToggleEnabled(next_button), current_slide = 1) : current_slide > total_slides ? (ToggleEnabled(prev_button), current_slide = 1) : [No clue what to put here];
```

Is there a better way of doing this in a more tidy way, or should I just keep using the if-elseif- ?

Comment: "*I've recently become informed of the ternary operator and it seems like an effective way of cleaning up my code*" I'd immediately cast doubt on your source.

Comment: You could use `&&` to short-circuit, but your first code-block is more readable imo, smaller doesn't always make things cleaner

Comment: I must apologise, I misread the first sentence. I thought somebody told you to use the conditional operator to clean up your code. That's not the case. So, instead, I'd just focus my doubt on the "cleaning up" part. There are *very few* cases where a conditional operator is easier to read and understand. Or rather, the cases aren't few in of themselves - you can use it effectively plenty of times. It's just that it's more often **mis**used.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the ternary operator should not be chained. As @VLAZ expressed their concerns in their comment, the ternary can become excessively difficult to read if you chain it in multiples. In this situation I would stick with the traditional `if-else`.

Take a look at the following:

```js
if (condition1) {
  // do stuff #1
} else if (condition2) {
  // do stuff #2
} else if (condition3) {
  // do stuff #3
} else {
  // do stuff #4
}
```

And compare the readability to the same in ternary (I tried to indent it clearly, but chained ternary formatting is a matter of opinion):

```js
condition1
? // do stuff #1
: condition2
  ? // do stuff #2
  : condition3
    ? // do stuff #3
    : // do stuff #4
```

To my eye the first option is a lot more readable. There is not much to be gained even if you would understand chained ternary very well, as it is (slightly) less efficient than traditional `if-else`.

Also of note should be the fact that ternary always needs the both the `?` and the `:`, which means there is always a "final `else`" that you must deal with.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the ternary operator is meant to **choose between answers or values,** based on **a condition**, e.g.:

```
const x = condition1 ? 1 : 2;
return condition2 ? func1(x) : func2(x);
```

If you don't use the resulting value from a ternary expression (as you do) then the usage becomes highly suspect to me, and I would most likely ask it to be changed in code review. Even more so if you move the assignment part to *BEHIND* the `?` and `:` selectors as you did.

Not everything that is possible, is also good style, good practice or recommended.